# Reverification of email using the rest end point POST /users/{id}/verify

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I'm trying to send a re-verification email when a user doesn't receives the verification email after createing the user. Below is the configuration:

```
Users.getVerifyOptions = function() {
  const defaultOptions = {
  type: 'email',
  from: 'no-reply@example.com',
  subject: 'Re-verification Email',
  template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../server/views/verify.ejs'),
  redirect: '',
  host: "mywebsite.com",
  port: 80
  };
return Object.assign({}, this.settings.verifyOptions || defaultOptions);
};

//Re-verify Method to render
Users.afterRemote('prototype.verify', function(context, user, next) {
  context.res.render('response', {
title: 'A Link to reverify your identity has been sent '+
  'to your email successfully',
content: 'Please check your email and click on the verification link '+
  'before logging in',
redirectTo: '',
redirectToLinkText: ''
  });
 });
```

Now the problem is, if the user is already verified, and the option `emailVerified` is set to true in the database then also the request to `POST /users/{id}/verify` generates a new verification token and sends an email. Is there any way to stop this endpoint to send any email if the `emailverified` option is set to `true` and return a message saying Email is already verified ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can try by check user.emailVerified is `true` or `false`

Example :

```
Users.afterRemote('prototype.verify', function (context, user, next) {
  if(!user.emailVerified) {
    context.res.render('response', {
      title: 'A Link to reverify your identity has been sent ' +
        'to your email successfully',
      content: 'Please check your email and click on the verification link ' +
        'before logging in',
      redirectTo: '',
      redirectToLinkText: ''
    });
  } else {
    return next('already verified');
  }
});
```

> Or else you can check verified user when login, when not verified send verification link.

Example :

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  User.login({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  }, 'user', function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      if(err.details && err.code === 'LOGIN_FAILED_EMAIL_NOT_VERIFIED'){
        //send verification link
      }
    }
  })
});
```